# How can i use express to pass a http request to origin server without any modify

Tags: express, proxy

I just what to use express server to catch a request and send it to origin server, then send back the response, but http-middleware-proxy must set a target option. it`s too complicate to create a http.request to do that, is there any other simple solutions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.